# String and pointers in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        char* a = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
        a = "1";
        free(a);
}
```

I have two questions regarding the above code:

1. Why does the code gives an error with free(a) when I initialize a like this :

> a = "1"

and doesn't give any error with free(a) when I initialize a like this :

> a[0] = '1'.

2. When I initialize a with 
   a[0] = '1' 
   and print the string a using 
   printf("%s", a) why do I get the result

> '1' 
>   
>   without declaring the second index with a '\0'?

Comment: a = "1"; doesn't fill a with a, it reassigns the pointer to some string "a" in memory. That string is compiled and fixed and can't/shouldn't be freed.

Comment: Quite literally, anytime a C program does this: `Type* p = malloc(...); p = ...` its wrong. Your program leaks memory in the first two lines, then free's the address of a read-only string literal..

Comment: About the second index with '\0'. That's pure luck, because memory contained '\0'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rules with *malloc* and *free* are that you must only pass to *free* a pointer that was allocated by a call to *malloc* (or one of its equivalents like *realloc* or *calloc*). You do not do that:

```
char* a = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
a = "1";
free(a);
```

When you call *free*, you pass *a* which was not allocated by a call to *malloc.* This results in your program having undefined behaviour.

---

The problem in your understanding is that I suspect you don't understand what *a = "1"* does.

I suspect that you imagine this to copy the string in to the memory that you allocated it does not. It changes the pointer *a* to point to a different address.

Indeed, by assigning to *a*, rather than the memory that it points to, you are leaking the allocated memory. Your code is exactly analogous to this:

```
int i = 1;
i = 2;
```

I'm sure you can see that the initialization of *i* is pointless because you immediately overwrite the value of *i* with a new value. That's exactly what you did with your pointer.

---

You can copy the string with `strcpy`. Like this:

```
char* a = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(a, "1");
free(a);
```

Similarly, when you wrote

```
char* a = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
a[0] = '1';
printf("%s", a);
free(a);
```

you were assigning the contents of the buffer allocated by your call to *malloc*. And hence the call to `free` is correct.

However, the string is not necessarily null-terminated when you do that. You observed that your *printf* appeared to work but that was just by chance.

The contents of *a[1]* are ill-defined and it seems that, by chance, *a[1]* did contain a null when you ran your program.

This is why you typically use a string function like *strcpy* to perform copies and ensure null-termination. You do of course need to take care not to overrun your buffer.

---

Finally, by definition, *sizeof(char) == 1* so you can write the *malloc* like this:

```
char* a = malloc(5);
```

Comment: When working with strings, it's a good idea to always use the functions in `string.h` like `strcpy` in this answer. Unless you really _do_ know what you are doing, it's less likely to break or give you an unwanted result, and it is likely more efficient than a home-grown function too.

Answer (score 4):

`a = "1";` is assigning read-only memory to `a`. `a` now points to a completely different memory location. The previous return of `malloc` is now lost so you will not be able to free the memory.

This is a disaster since, not including the memory leak, you have *undefined behaviour* when attempting to `free` the new value of `a`. **Boom**. Futhermore, if you attempt to modify the contents of `a` then that's *undefined behaviour* too. **Boom**.

Without the errant reassignment, `a[0] = '1'` is perfectly fine: you're *deferencing* the zeroth element of the allocated character buffer and setting its value to literal `1`.

But if you attempt `printf("%s", a)` on this then, **boom**! More *undefined behaviour* since you haven't null-terminated the character buffer which `printf` requires you to do in order to prevent it from accessing memory that you don't own. To to that, use `a[1] = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
a = "1";
```

`a` no longer points to the memory you allocated with `malloc`. Rather, it points to a string constant, stored in the text segment of your program. Naturally, such a pointer can't be freed. The original `a` pointer is lost.

As for your second question, that is undefined behavior. a[1] happened to be a null character by sheer dumb luck, but you should of course not rely on this happening.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "1";
```

makes `a` point to a string literal, which is stored in read-only memory. You can not `free()` that part of memory.

`a[0] = '1';` makes it to store a value of `31` (since that's the hex ascii value of 1) in the first byte that `a` points to. `a` still points to address that malloc had returned, therefore freeing it is legal operation. `a[0]` is the same as `*(a + 0)`, so you see that address of `a` is untouched, contents where `a` **points to** are changed.

Other answers already have the information about null terminating your char array. You should know that `printf()` stops writing values to stdout when it encouters a null terminator. If there's `'1'` at 0th position and no `'\0'` at 1st position of your array, you might see some garbage values.

You should know that `"1"` and `'1'` are two different things.

Answer (score -2):

Corrected program with inline comments for your understanding:

```
int main(void)
{
  char* a = (char *) malloc(5 * sizeof(char)); // prefer casting from void * to char *
  // a = "1"; -- wrong conversion from string constant to char *
  strcpy(a, "1"); // this would work
  free(a);
}
```

Comment: Permission to remove the `malloc` cast?

Comment: Nope, then you should use strdup, but also free before strdup first.

Comment: This is a C question. You should not cast the result of `malloc()` in C. The cast is not needed and may hide useful compiler warnings.

Comment: LHS is char *, rhs is void *, what's the harm in casting? It is good programming practice

Comment: Simple, lhs is char *, that's why? Can you cast to anything else? Come on!

Comment: C allows implicit casting from/to `void *`.

Comment: Yes, but what's the harm in explicit casting? Downvoting because of being explicit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc  I expect that you received downvotes for the original version of the answer which incorrectly stated *need casting from `void*` to `char*`*

Comment: Often the declaration of a pointer like `char *a` and subsequent assignments, like `a = malloc(...)` are lines apart.  Using the style of `a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);` is easier to _maintain_.  Should the type of pointer change, something like `a = (char *) malloc(5 * sizeof(char));` get coded, not only does the original type change, every allocation for `a` needs 2 edits.  Simpler and less error prone to use `a = malloc(n * sizeof *a);`.

Comment: That's why C++11 has come up with auto. Type checking is so weak in C!